# Custom Post Types CPT en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

estoy tratando de acometer la siguiente estructura en wordpress y no se cómo hacerlo. Agradecería si me pudieran ayudar.

La estructura es la siguiente:

Tengo un **Custom Post Type "Destinos"** y quiero que cada uno de esos destinos tengan como hijos elementos de otro **Custom Post Type "Páginas Informativas"**, a su vez quiero que dichas "páginas informativas" puedan ser hijas de otras "páginas informativas".

Además de esto me gustaría que dichos destinos se les pudieran asociar taxonomias hijas para categorizar otro **CPT llamado "lugares"**.

### Ejemplo 1:

- Alicante (CPT Destino)
- ++ Mejores zonas (CPT página informativa)
- ++ Cómo desplazarse (CPT página informativa)
- ++++ Cómo desplazarse en bus (CPT página informativa)
- ++ Restaurantes (taxonomia)
- ++++ Restaurante pepe (CPT lugar)
- ++++ Restaurante maria (CPT lugar)

### Ejemplo 2:

- Valencia (CPT Destino)
- ++ ¿Que visitar? (CPT página informativa)
- ++ ¿Donde ir de compras? (CPT página informativa)
- ++++ Ir de compras de ropa (CPT página informativa)
- ++ Museos (taxonomia)
- ++++ Museo arqueológico (CPT lugar)
- ++++ Museo de las ciencias (CPT lugar)

Nota: Deseo que **cada CPT destino tenga sus propias páginas informativas**, taxonomías y CPT lugares **independientes del resto de destinos**.

¿Me podéis ayudar por favor?, no consigo entender como estructurar esto.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

No mencionas como generaste tus CPTs. Yo uso dos plugins para lograr tu requerimiento: Custom Post Type UI y Advanced Custom Fields

- Para crear CPTs y sus taxonomías (Plugin Custom Post Type UI):

  1.- Crea los CPTs "Destinos" y "Páginas Informativas" con CPT UI/Add Edit Post Types

  2.- Crea la taxonomía con CPT UI/Add Edit Taxonomies

  3.- En la taxonomía puedes especificar a dual CPT se lo vas a anexar, la opción es "Attach to Post Type"

[image: Asignar taxonomia a CPT]

- Para hacer que "Destinos" y "Páginas informativas" tengan hijos de tipo "Páginas Informativas" (Plugin Advanced Custom Fields)

  4.- Crea un grupo de campos en Custom Fields/Add New (le puedes poner el nombre que quieras al grupo, es solamente descriptivo)
  5.- Añade un campo con el botón "Add field", que el tipo de campo  sea "Post Object" y el filtro de post type sea "Página Informativa

[image: Anadir campo]"

6.- Asegúrate que en las Reglas sean "Si el post type es igual a destinos" o "Si el post type es igual a pagina informativa"

[image: Reglas]

Lo que lograrás es que al final del editor de tu "destino" o "página infomativa" aparecerá el campo Página informativa, para que lo elijas

[image: Campo para pag informativa]

La combinación de ambos plugins da bastante flexibilidad en cualquier tipo de CPT de Wordpress (no está limitado  a CPTs propios, puedes modificar CPTs ya existentes como elementos de menú, media, etc). Te recomiendo experimentar con ellos para sacarles todo el potencial.

Comment: Gracias Gabriel por tu respuesta. Olvidé mencionar que estoy usando Custom Post Type UI y Advanced Custom Fields para crear los CPT y los fields igual que tú en tu respuesta. Creo que he entendido tu respuesta y se adapta a lo que necesito pero faltaría la parte 2. ¿Como podría hacer que la taxonomía fuera hija del destino y sirviera para categorizar solo los lugares hijos de ese destino?

Comment: Hola @Ridewalker, Acabo de editar los puntos 2 y 3. En realidad una taxonomía es una forma de clasificar, y solo puede ser "hija" de otras taxonomías En el paso 3 permites que se pueda ASIGNAR la taxonomía que creaste al Post Type que desees, en este caso, el CPT "Destino"

Comment: Entiendo lo que me quieres decir, sin embargo yo lo que necesito es poder crear términos de taxonomía que sólo estuvieran disponibles para categorizar los lugares de un destino en concreto. Por ejemplo: que el término "restaurantes" sólo estuviera disponible para los lugares de Alicante y el término "museos" sólo para los lugares de Valencia. De esta manera yo podría tener una página de archivo en la que listar "los restaurantes de alicante" con sus propias metatitle y descripción. ,¿Se te ocurre cómo llegar a esto?

Comment: Hola Ridewalker!  Se puede usar el valor de la taxonomía del post para apuntar directamente a una taxonomía en específico. Para ello, crea un grupo de campos en CPTs con "Post Taxonomy" igual al "Lugar" que quieras. Espero te funciones este método. Saludos!